# Why do I convert win32 intptr to c# int array, data is wrong

Tags: c#, c, winapi

**Win32 program:**

```
int* EC_GetGin(int icard)
{
    int gin[4]; 
    gin[0] = 1;
    gin[1] = 2;
    gin[2] = 3;
    gin[3] = 4;
    
    return gin;
}
```

**C#**

```
[DllImport("test.dll", EntryPoint = "EC_GetGin", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr EC_GetGin(int icard);


 int[] bRawData = new int[4];
 IntPtr pRawData = EC_GetGin(1);

 Marshal.Copy(pRawData, bRawData, 0, bRawData.Length);
 Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pRawData);
```

I can not get the correct value of the array. Could anyone help me and explain me why this happens?

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a stack-allocated array. That memory will be freed when your function returns;.

Comment: @canton I'll take "things that C# thankfully spots for you if you try it" for 10 :)

Comment: In addition to the previous problem, calling `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` on something that was not allocated using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` (or `LocalAlloc` in C) is wrong as well

Comment: Your program would work if you changed this line in your DLL `int gin[4];` to `int *gin = LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, 4 * sizeof(int));`

Comment: What should I do to achieve my goal

Comment: As for what you should do, well, you should change both the DLL and the C# code. In an ideal world you have the C# code allocate the array, and the C code in your DLL populate it. In other words, don't do what I said in my previous comment. Can you do that?

Comment: `BOOL EC_GetGin(int* icards, int size) { if(size < 4) return FALSE; icards[0] = 1; ... return TRUE;}`   `public static extern bool EC_GetGin(ref int[] icard, int size);` `var cards = new int[4]; EC_GetGin(ref cards, cards.Length);` ... edit: you may also change size to ref if you need more than 4 and return there required size ( `BOOL EC_GetGin(int* icards, int* size) if(size[0] < requiredSize) {  
size[0] = requiredSize  return FALSE; }`

Answer (score -1):

The problem is from your win32 program.
The `gin` variable is allocated in stack and will be destroyed when `EC_GetGin` ends.
The best practice for this is:

1. C# prepares the buffer & pass that buffer's address to Win32

```
int bufferSize = 4;
IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize * sizeof(int));
EC_GetGin(buffer, bufferSize, 1);
```

2. Win32 writes value to that given buffer

```
int EC_GetGin(int* buffer, int bufferSize, int icard)
{
    # Should do more check on the buffer to make sure it has enough writable space
    buffer[0] = 1;
    buffer[1] = 2;
    buffer[2] = 3;
    buffer[3] = 4;
    
    # Can return error state so the C# can handle it
    return 0; 
}
```

3. C# use the buffer for its business then free it up after using.

```
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
```

**My principle**: Let the creator destroys its created assets.

Comment: Why not pass in a C# array, rather than using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`? The marshaller knows what to do with it.

Comment: The first two sentences are fine. The answer goes downhill from there. You allocate 4 bytes rather than the 16 that are needed. But you should not use explicit allocation of unmanaged memory. Use `int[]` as the argument for the function, and let the marshaler handle pinning it, etc.

Comment: Now you're passing in 4 as the `bufferSize`, when you probably meant to pass 16. You also don't show how to turn that `IntPtr` into an `int[]`. As before, just use an `int[]` throughout and let the marshaller handle it

Comment: By convention "size" is a byte count, and "length" is an element count. Your arg should be named `bufferLength`. So, this is better, but all this discussion vanishes if you stop allocating unmanaged memory explicitly, and pass `int[]` as nature intended.

Comment: Great comment @David Hefferman & canton7. Thanks.
Why don't you post an answer so the author can solve his problem?
I prefer managing the buffer by myself since I had experience crash with passing the array directly and I haven't know what actually the Marshaller do with it (my bad).

Comment: I don't want to post an answer really since there are already hundreds that explain how to do this.